# How do I try the Gtk Wayland backend in ubuntu 13.10

Tags: gtk, wayland

Is there any way to run any Gtk application inside the Weston compositor in ubuntu 13.10?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, just rebuild the GTK library with the Wayland back-end support and you'll be good to go.

GTK can be rebuilt with `--enable-wayland-backend`

Although don't expect every GTK applications to work perfectly.